# N1QL/Couchbase - Show all the events produced each day, where don't know how many different days maybe in the table

Tags: sql, couchbase, sql++

Suppose I have a bucket with documents that looks like this:

```
[
{"topic":..., "event":..., "message":...,"date":......}
.
.
.
]
```

How can I write a query that groups all messages of a specific event type for each day, without hard-coding the date and suppose we do not know how many different dates are there in the bucket?

I'm thinking of getting the distinct dates first. (For example, `SELECT DISTINCT(date) FROM bucket`).
Is there a way to loop through these days and put all events with the same date into an array, and union all arrays together as a nested array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Aggregate query.

```
SELECT b.date, ARRAY_AGG(b) AS docs
FROM mybucket AS b
WHERE b.event = "myevent"
GROUP BY b.date ;
```

If date is ISO-8601 format use https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html date functions group by desired format.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT_STR(b.date,"1111-11-11") AS day, ARRAY_AGG(b) AS docs
FROM mybucket AS b
WHERE b.event = "myevent"
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT_STR(b.date,"1111-11-11") ;
```